# Размещение кнопок в виджете QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qpushbutton, qlistwidget

Скажите, какой есть в *PyQt5* виджет, в котором можно отображать кнопки?

Например:
по нажатию кнопки "привет", внизу в определенном виджете (например `QListWidget`, где можно отображать другие виджеты) появятся несколько кликабельных кнопок.

Какой есть виджет, в котором можно размещать кнопки?

Годного примера с `QListView` и `QListWidget` с размещением кнопок в инете не смог найти, только размещение текста в виджетах.

Но как быть с кнопками?

Это сделано вручную:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S. Nick обновил

Comment: Просто разместите на `QWidget` (или `QFrame`, или `QGroupBox`) + `QHBoxLayout`, виджет можно спрятать и показать когда нужно

Comment: Покажите пример, который к вас есть.

Comment: @gil9red мне неизвестно заранее количество кнопок, они появляется в рандомном количестве и нужно их всех разместить

Comment: @Евгений, ну, сохраняете в переменную `QHBoxLayout` и когда нужно в него добавляете кнопки, виджет отобразит кнопки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я очень надеюсь, что в следующий раз, будете предоставлять минимально-воспроизводимый пример.

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5     import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class Input_Box(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent= None):
        super(Input_Box, self).__init__(parent)

        open_message = QtWidgets.QLabel("Enter Value:")
        self.txt     = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        save         = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Save', clicked=self.accept)
        cancel       = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Cancel', clicked=self.reject)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.setSpacing(10)
        grid.addWidget(open_message, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.txt, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(save, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(cancel, 2, 1)
        self.setFixedSize(self.sizeHint())

    def save(self):
        value = self.txt.text()
        return value


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello World")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        addButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add', clicked=self.add_button)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.setSpacing(10)
        grid.addWidget(label)
        grid.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        grid.addWidget(addButton)

    def add_button(self):
        input_box = Input_Box()
        input_box.setWindowTitle("Window 2")
        if input_box.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            val = input_box.save()
            newButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'{val}')
            newButton.clicked.connect(lambda btn, text=val: self.onClicked(text))
    
            listWidgetItem = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem() 
            listWidgetItem.setSizeHint(newButton.sizeHint())
            self.listWidget.addItem(listWidgetItem)
            self.listWidget.setItemWidget(listWidgetItem, newButton)
            self.listWidget.scrollToItem(listWidgetItem)
            
    def onClicked(self, text):
        print(text)    
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Простенький пример размещения кнопок на компоновщике по клику на кнопку <kbd>Hello</kbd>

Попробуйте:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QFrame, QPushButton


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button_hello = QPushButton('Hello')
        self.button_hello.clicked.connect(self.add_button)

        self.layout_buttons = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout_buttons.addStretch()  # Это добавит пружину, прижимающую виджеты вверх

        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.frame.setMinimumSize(200, 200)
        self.frame.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Box)
        self.frame.setLayout(self.layout_buttons)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_hello)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.frame)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def add_button(self):
        button = QPushButton('Кнопка')
        self.layout_buttons.insertWidget(0, button)  # Добавление в начало, с пружиной это прижмет вверх
        # self.layout_buttons.addWidget(button)  # Добавление в конец, с пружиной это прижмет вниз


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот (клик три раза на <kbd>Hello</kbd>):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]