# Создание label'a внутри фрейма по нажатии на кнопку, PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

День добрый, появилась нужда в создание некого label'а внутри фрейма по нажатии на кнопку. Написал программу в которую вписываются задачи выбираются некоторые группы и нажимается кнопка отправки. По нажатии этой кнопки в зависимости от выбранной группы выбирается вкладка в Qtabwidget и в заранее мюсозданный фрейм добавляется напечатанный текст и checkBox (для отметке о выполнении). И единственное в чём проблема это создание этих 2ух элементов. Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, Ваш код

Comment: Возможности показать нету, только если фотография, но не думаю что это выход... Мне интересно только создание новых элементов,  как мне кажется код тут мало чем поможет

Comment: Возможно один из вариантов решения вы можете найти [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1212255/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5-pyqt5)

Comment: Если вам действительно нужна помощь, составьте пожалуйста  [mcve] , который демонстрирует вашу проблему и лучше объясните, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.